# angularjs error on $$broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular script, which broadcasts an event on the $rootScope (using $$broadcast).
The version of angular I'm using is 1.1.4

On some occassions , this throws an exception inside the angular code:

Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null.

Does any one has a clue what might be causing this error ? Unfortunately the code in which this error occurs is to big to post, but maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

The angular code where it happens is :

```
   // Insanity Warning: scope depth-first traversal
      // yes, this code is a bit crazy, but it works and we have tests to prove it!
      // this piece should be kept in sync with the traversal in $digest
      if (!(next = (current.$$childHead || (current !== target && current.$$nextSibling)))) {
        while(current !== target && !(next = current.$$nextSibling)) {
```

on the while statement

update:  the broadcast is excuted from inside a clicked event on an external component
the click event is an property of a config object for the external component.

Comment: Ouch.  I think that code runs during a digest cycle to find all of the scopes.  It appears `current` is not defined.  Are you doing anything odd with scopes?  like creating your own, or destroying them manually?

Comment: not that I'm aware of... see update for more info about the situation where it happens

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem lies in the use or lack of use of $$apply on the scope. Sometimes I needed to use $$apply on other occassions I already was in the apply phase... Sp I ended up implementing safeApply (found somewhere on the internet). Wonder why this is not standard implemented in angular because it is really simple to implement, and it simplifies coding

Comment: You might be wondering why all the downvotes. Well, what you speak of is considered an anti-pattern by the Angular team. Although the "safe apply" approach works, it is not the proper solution. You're better off wrapping things in $timeout() so your code gets applied properly during the next digest. See here regarding the anti-pattern: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

Answer (score 12):

```
$timeout(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

`$timeout` without a wait time works as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I had to wrap $on function like this $scope.$on(...) { $timeout(...() { myStuff(); })}. After hours of frustration! This is using angular 1.0.8.

Comment: thanks..saved me a few hours of frustration I'm sure!

Comment: thanks, this also worked for me! Do you have any explanation, why this works? In my example, I am calling `scope.$destroy()` when listening on the event. With $timeout its working fine, without I get the exception on every second call.

Comment: It forces the function to queue up for the next `$digest` rather than interrupting the current one and causing problems with other items that may have yet to finish.